# Why do I have to use replace in my regex for Palindromes?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing some challenges at FreeCodeCamp and I got lost in a basic challenge that
asks to Check for Palindromes. In the solution I had to do the following:

```
str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '').toLowerCase();
```

But I don't understand the reason I have to use the replace method and the regular expression.

Anybody can help me, please?

Comment: Your question should indicate which language you are using. The regex part is fairly universal (and fairly simple) but I don't recognize this particular language offhand; anybody who is fluent in it could probably provide a better explanation, as well as possibly better non-regex ways to normalize a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code:

```
str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '').toLowerCase()
```

You are getting rid of all the characters that are not letters from A-Z and a-z, and then you are setting the replaced string to lower case. The `^` at the beginning of a character class `[`..`]` like `[^...]` means `not this characters`. So, `[a-z]` means *match letter from a to z* while `[^a-z]` means *match anything but letter from a to z*

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eR6mI6/1)**

There are plenty of online regex tool explaining the patterns. From Regex101 you can see:

```
/[^a-zA-Z]/g
   [^a-zA-Z] match a single character not present in the list below
      a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
      A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
   g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```